# How to view the image in the browser with presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, acl

I am using AWS SDK to sign the URL for viewing the object in the Browser tab on getting it. But when I open the URL with window.open(url) -> Its downloading the file.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileKey,
    Expires: 90
   })
```

Is there a way to view it from the browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: Can't you insert that url inside <img> tag of an html file?

Comment: Nope , even if I insert inside the src of the image tag its not showing the image itself @OsamaBinSaleem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's downloading the file because you don't have the correct MIME type set on the object in S3. You need to set the MIME type of the image in the `ContentType` attribute of the S3 object.